# Quartz for iregular interval of hours

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz library to schedule `Thread` (using `Jobs`).

My boss ask me if it is possible to solve this situation with Quartz:

There is one Process that must be executed only days of the week at 00:00hs, 5:00hs, 9:00hs, and other diferent hours. As you can see, there isn't regular interval of the repeat. There are 5 o 6 different hours.

Is there some `ScheduleBuilder` to solve this situation?

I tried with `DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder` but this Schedule work for regular interval of time.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to schedule job every hour. And within the Job check current time to see if it is 00.00 or 05.00 or 09.00. If it is,  do your Job, else do nothing.

Comment: Thats works, but is not the rightest way to do, don't you think? Anyway, thanks for the idea, maybe I used it

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, if you use a  CronTrigger , see: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger.

This way you will be able to schedule the job only on specific times, using an expression similar to Unix cron expressions.

For your case, if you like to start a job on each working week day at 0, 5 and 9 hours, you will use an expression like `0 0 0,5,9 ? * MON-FRI`

Comment: I saw that solution, but I still could test it a lot. I couldn't make it work for different hours. Thanks for the answer